# writing to a file using one of the key as index and other key as value

Tags: python

I am very new to programming as well as to python.

I have been trying to implement it, but without success and would like ur help.

I have a dictionary with weird key values. I need to use one of the key as my index number and other i.e second key as the value along with the value stored in the dictionary as the third column.

For e.g if the dictionary is

```
{'Michael', 'Student<matriculation no>', 'marks obtained' :  40 }
```

the result should be like this

```
Name                  Admission no                 marks obtained

Michael              matriculation no                    40

sara                 matriculation no                    60
```

where matriculation no is the value extracted from the second key of the dictionary(different for each value)

and this goes on for about 100 rows.

kindly suggest a method to do this.

Comment: That's not a valid dictionary..

Comment: Dictionaries have 1 key and 1 value. Your values may include lists or tuples, but you may not have more than 1 key.

Comment: thanks Brendan and Bill
@Bill : now i got the difference understood well enough, this was confusing me for long time. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have multiple keys. In your example, your key is the tuple `('Michael', 'Student', 'marks obtained')` (your dictionary syntax is wrong, by the way: it should be `{('Michael', 'Student', 'marks obtained') : 40}` based on what you're implying).

If you are guaranteed that no two students will have the same name (perhaps you might include last name and middle initial!) then you may use just their names as keys. Then, it would make sense to have the value be a tuple `(matriculation, marks obtained)`. Like so: `{"Michael" : ('Student', 40)}`.

When you want to print these students, you may say `print name, students[name][0], "no", students[name][1]`, where `students` is your dictionary and `name` is a string which is the student's name e.g. `'Michael'`.

I'm not sure what else you can have for matriculation besides `'Student'` by the way. It seems to me that you don't need to include that, unless you can in fact have other values for that.

A good metaphor here is to think of `'Michael'` as having some data associated with him, i.e. his matriculation status and the number of marks received. The state of being matriculated does not have `'Michael'` associated with it (particularly) nor does having received 40 marks have `'Michael'` associated with it (particularly), because these things can happen to other people. So, the proper key is the student's name. Keys are supposed to be unique - when they are not, you run into a problem known as collision, in which two or more data (values) are associated with the same thing (key).

---

**Big edit**:

After looking at your edited post it seems that your key should actually be the matriculation number, since it is never the same. So now your dictionary should be `{matriculation_no : (name, marks)}`. And printing is now `print students[matriculation_no][0], "Admission", matriculation_no, students[matriculation_no][1]` or something like that. It depends on whether you wanted `"Admission"` in your string.

---

*Minor edit*:

If you want to write to a file, use [`file.write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) instead.

Comment: hi 2rs2ts,
thanks but my real problem is writing these values to a file.

Comment: @Michael_Scofield then instead of saying `print`, use `write()`. Here are the file I/O operations in Python: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: thanks all of u guys :)
i could finally extract all required variables, write them to a text file and then import in Matlab
cheers :)